# Fitsio pip install giving bad register errors, using MacPorts gcc on 64-bit MacBook Pro

Tags: python, gcc, 64-bit, installation, pip

I'm trying to install this fitsio python package: https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio.

I have tried 
    `pip install fitsio`
and `python setup.py install` in the fitsio directory and they both give similar 'bad register' errors. Here is the beginning of the output from pip install:

```
Downloading/unpacking fitsio
Downloading fitsio-0.9.6.tar.gz (5.9MB): 5.9MB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina/fitsio/setup.py) egg_info for package fitsio
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking bzlib.h usability... yes
checking bzlib.h presence... yes
checking for bzlib.h... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using GNU Fortran...
yes
cfitsio: == Adding wrapper support for GNU Fortran...
 done
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -arch i386 -arch x86_64... no
cfitsio: == Using gcc version 4.8.2
checking "whether ftruncate works"... "yes"
checking "whether long long is defined"... "yes"
checking "whether system V style IPC services are supported"... "yes"
checking "do we have flock_t defined in sys/fcntl.h"... "no"
checking "do we have flock_t defined in sys/flock.h"... "no"
checking "do we have union semun defined"... "yes"
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing connect... none required
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cfitsio.pc

    Congratulations, Makefile update was successful.
    You may want to run "make" now.

gcc -c -o ./buffers.o -g -O2  -Dg77Fortran -fPIC -fno-common -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_BZLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_BZIP2=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MATH_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_FTRUNCATE=1 -DHAVE_LONGLONG=1 -DHAVE_SHMEM_SERVICES=1 -DHAVE_UNION_SEMUN=1 -DHAVE_NET_SERVICES=1 buffers.c
gcc -c -o ./cfileio.o -g -O2  -Dg77Fortran -fPIC -fno-common -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_BZLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_BZIP2=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MATH_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_FTRUNCATE=1 -DHAVE_LONGLONG=1 -DHAVE_SHMEM_SERVICES=1 -DHAVE_UNION_SEMUN=1 -DHAVE_NET_SERVICES=1 cfileio.c`
```

then lots more lines of gcc then:

```
 ar rv libcfitsio.a buffers.o cfileio.o checksum.o drvrfile.o drvrmem.o drvrnet.o drvrsmem.o drvrgsiftp.o editcol.o edithdu.o eval_l.o eval_y.o eval_f.o fitscore.o getcol.o getcolb.o getcold.o getcole.o getcoli.o getcolj.o getcolk.o getcoll.o getcols.o getcolsb.o getcoluk.o getcolui.o getcoluj.o getkey.o group.o grparser.o histo.o iraffits.o modkey.o putcol.o putcolb.o putcold.o putcole.o putcoli.o putcolj.o putcolk.o putcoluk.o putcoll.o putcols.o putcolsb.o putcolu.o putcolui.o putcoluj.o putkey.o region.o scalnull.o swapproc.o wcssub.o wcsutil.o imcompress.o quantize.o ricecomp.o pliocomp.o fits_hcompress.o fits_hdecompress.o simplerng.o zlib/adler32.o zlib/crc32.o zlib/deflate.o zlib/infback.o zlib/inffast.o zlib/inflate.o zlib/inftrees.o zlib/trees.o zlib/uncompr.o zlib/zcompress.o zlib/zuncompress.o zlib/zutil.o f77_wrap1.o f77_wrap2.o f77_wrap3.o f77_wrap4.o; \
        ranlib libcfitsio.a;
ar: creating archive libcfitsio.a
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: libcfitsio.a(drvrgsiftp.o) has no symbols
a - buffers.o
a - cfileio.o
a - checksum.o
a - drvrfile.o
a - drvrmem.o
a - drvrnet.o
a - drvrsmem.o
a - drvrgsiftp.o
a - editcol.o
a - edithdu.o
a - eval_l.o
a - eval_y.o
a - eval_f.o
a - fitscore.o
a - getcol.o
a - getcolb.o
a - getcold.o
a - getcole.o
a - getcoli.o
a - getcolj.o
a - getcolk.o
a - getcoll.o
a - getcols.o
a - getcolsb.o
a - getcoluk.o
a - getcolui.o
a - getcoluj.o
a - getkey.o
a - group.o
a - grparser.o
a - histo.o
a - iraffits.o
a - modkey.o
a - putcol.o
a - putcolb.o
a - putcold.o
a - putcole.o
a - putcoli.o
a - putcolj.o
a - putcolk.o
a - putcoluk.o
a - putcoll.o
a - putcols.o
a - putcolsb.o
a - putcolu.o
a - putcolui.o
a - putcoluj.o
a - putkey.o
a - region.o
a - scalnull.o
a - swapproc.o
a - wcssub.o
a - wcsutil.o
a - imcompress.o
a - quantize.o
a - ricecomp.o
a - pliocomp.o
a - fits_hcompress.o
a - fits_hdecompress.o
a - simplerng.o
a - zlib/adler32.o
a - zlib/crc32.o
a - zlib/deflate.o
a - zlib/infback.o
a - zlib/inffast.o
a - zlib/inflate.o
a - zlib/inftrees.o
a - zlib/trees.o
a - zlib/uncompr.o
a - zlib/zcompress.o
a - zlib/zuncompress.o
a - zlib/zutil.o
a - f77_wrap1.o
a - f77_wrap2.o
a - f77_wrap3.o
a - f77_wrap4.o
ranlib: file: libcfitsio.a(drvrgsiftp.o) has no symbols

Downloading/unpacking numpy from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz#md5=a1ed53432dbcd256398898d35bc8e645 (from fitsio)
Downloading numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz (4.0MB): 4.0MB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina/numpy/setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
Running from numpy source directory.

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: fitsio, numpy
Running setup.py install for fitsio
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `stand_alone'.
building 'fitsio._fitsio_wrap' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/Christina/anaconda/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Icfitsio3370 -I/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/Christina/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c fitsio/fitsio_pywrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/fitsio/fitsio_pywrap.o -arch i386 -arch x86_64
In file included from /Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from fitsio/fitsio_pywrap.c:28:
/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
```

where the last line about deprecated NumPy API is something else I cannot resolve, but it seems that it can be ignored.

After this there are a LOT of lines that look like these:

```
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:16:bad register name `%rbp'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:18:bad register name `%rbx'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:20:bad register name `%rdx'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:21:bad register name `%rsp'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:26:`L4(%rip)' is not a valid base/index expression
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:29:`movslq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:30:bad register name `%rdx'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:31:bad register name `%rax'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:50:bad register name `%rsi)'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:54:bad register name `%rbx)'
/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T//cckS5jL0.s:58:bad register name `%rsp'
```

and finally ends with

```
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...


    Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina... Command /Users/Christina/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina/f\ itsio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1\ d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip-ww4Fvd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb1\ 4d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina/fitsio 
    Exception information: 

    Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main 
    status = self.run(options, args) 
    File "/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run 
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path) 
    File "/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs) 
    File "/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
     File "/Users/Christina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) 
    InstallationError: Command /Users/Christina/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pi\ p_build_Christina/fitsio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/fol\ ders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip-ww4Fvd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/\ folders/3p/v45zthb14d1d108h9y8xg6cw0000gn/T/pip_build_Christina/fitsio
```

From extensive googling, it seems that the bad register issues come from a confusion in gcc flags over 32-bit vs 64-bit systems. BUT setup.py seems to have figured out that I have a 64-bit and wants to pass `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` to gcc but this line:

```
checking whether gcc accepts -arch i386 -arch x86_64... no
```

leads me to believe that it can't for some reason. I have no idea why. I am running the MacPorts gcc version 4.8. Here are some checks I did to make sure this was the case:

```
$port select --list gcc
Available versions for gcc:
llvm-gcc42
mp-gcc48 (active)
none

$which gcc
/opt/local/bin/gcc
```

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own..

I went into setup.py and changed this line:

```
if platform.system()=='Darwin':
extra_compile_args=['-arch','i386',                                                     
                    '-arch','x86_64']
extra_link_args=['-arch','i386',                                                        
                 '-arch','x86_64']
```

to remove the i386. Like so:

```
if platform.system()=='Darwin':
extra_compile_args=['-arch','x86_64']
extra_link_args=['-arch','x86_64']
```

This removed the bad register errors.